# How to prevent Maven from replacing ${id} in a Struts2 application

Tags: java, maven, struts2

I develop a Java application on Struts2. We were previously building using Ant, and are preparing to transition towards Maven.

When I run `mvn package`, all instances of `${id}` in `struts.xml` were getting replaced by `com.appname:appname:war:localhost-SNAPSHOT` in the `/target` folder (which contains the build output).

We ended up with a lot of broken redirections.

For example, this is what was originally in `/src`:

```
<action name="doaddadmin" class="dashboardaction.DoAddAdmin">
   <result name="ERROR">/pages/error.jsp</result>
   <result type="redirectAction">
      <param name="actionName">manageadmins</param>
      <param name="id">${id}</param>
   </result>
</action>
```

But it became like this in `/target`:

```
<action name="doaddadmin" class="dashboardaction.DoAddAdmin">
   <result name="ERROR">/pages/error.jsp</result>
   <result type="redirectAction">
      <param name="actionName">manageadmins</param>
      <param name="id">com.appname:appname:war:localhost-SNAPSHOT</param>
   </result>
</action>
```

My `pom.xml` currently looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- Version attributes will be updated by automated Github Workflow -->
    <groupId>com.appname</groupId>
    <artifactId>appname</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>appname</name>
    <description>AppName Platform</description>
    <url>https://github.com/appname/platform-appname</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <revision>localhost-SNAPSHOT</revision>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <!-- Localhost environment -->
        <profile>
            <id>localhost</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <config.livemode>false</config.livemode>
                <config.web_url>http://localhost:8081/</config.web_url>
                <config.log4jfile>${sys:catalina.base}/logs/appname-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</config.log4jfile>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>javaxt.com</id>
            <url>http://www.javaxt.com/maven</url>
        </repository>
        <!-- Our custom packages are hosted here -->
        <repository>
            <id>github-appname</id>
            <name>GitHub AppName Apache Maven Packages</name>
            <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/appname/platform-appname</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- ...other dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <pluginManagement>
            <!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>github-appname</id>
            <name>GitHub AppName Apache Maven Packages</name>
            <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/appname/platform-appname</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

**How do I suppress Maven from automatically replacing all instances of `${id}` in `struts.xml`?**

Comment: Please show your pom file...

Comment: First if the file is really located in `src` then it will not being filtered as you described. That means you have put that file into a different location. Furthermore the usage of `${revision}` in your pom file is wrong (see https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html)...

Comment: That file is located in `src`, more specifically - `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Ah that's what I expected. So `src` is not correct so correctly in `src/main/resources` but that means you have activated filtering ...which is off by default... and the part about `${revision}` will result in unusable pom files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to deactivate resource filtering as described here:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! I've removed the entire chunk of <resources>...</resources> and the ${id}s no longer get replaced.